# why not using the device-width media query?

Tags: css, iframe, media-queries

Heho people,
**what again are the drawbacks of using the device-width-media-queries?**
The background of my quest is:
--> a websiteB I control and which has to be responsive
--> in an iframe of 100% width and height
--> on a webpageA with possibly NO viewport-meta-tag
Therefore on mobile, the mobile browser renders webpageA without a viewport-meta-tag, i.e. it will be big. So the iframe getting *big values* for it's own responsiveness and my webpageBs normal width-media-query (which is recommended so many times) is not triggering, because it needs *small values* . . .
Nonetheless the device-width-media-query is getting the *right values*, so why not using it?

Answer (score 0):

A device's width has nothing to do with a device's viewport which is what the browser will be using. Usually in mobile devices the viewport is actually bigger then shrunken down into the device's width.

Targeting anything for a media query other than the actual wrapping body (i.e. the viewport) of the document is just asking for issue in design later.

As to the browser rendering without a viewport I think you may have your terminology off and may I ask what you are building with an iframe? Unless app software specific frames are generally discouraged from structural mark up usage.

Comment: changed the 'without viewport' to 'without a viewport-tag' and 'getting small values' to 'needs small values'
in fact I need the iframe for a webapp, which of course has to be responsive for mobile devices.
I would use the device-width to get nice breakpoints to know, on which kind of device I am. And that is exactly the information I need to tell my layout, how proportions should be; if the menu is on the left or at the top, ...

Comment: I'm trying to follow your question. My understanding is website B contains the iframe, which is also the site you control. As to Website A that has no viewport meta tag it would by default use the iframe as the viewport dimensions if this is where it will load. Without knowing what the app is doing, where Website A or B are loaded to and more concerning the project its really hard to give an accurate answer to the problem.

Comment: opposite: 'a **websiteB** I control and which has to be responsive
--> **in an iframe** of 100% width and height --> **on a webpageA** with possibly NO viewport-meta-tag'
[wrote it in reverse logic, sorry for that.]